# Tornado translation facility and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, tornado

I am trying to make a bilingual website (English & Greek). I am using tornado and I put global function `_()` in my templates. The translation comes directly from a .csv. Everything is fine in html so I can write `{{_("Hello")}}` and if the user locale is Greek the word "Hello" is translated in Greek. However, I have no idea how to do the same thing in javascript. For example:

```
foo.html("Hello")
```

I dont know how to enable javascript to work with Tornado localization.

Thanks

Comment: Probably the easiest is to serve up your javascript using templates, and use the same function to do the substitution on the server side.

Comment: What do you mean by serve up??

Comment: Sorry, I mean: handle the request for the javascript file by rendering a template, in the same way that you do for HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested these two plugins:

1) http://recursive-design.com/blog/2008/02/21/jquery-i18n-translation-plugin/
2) http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html

Probably we'll use these!